# Android: HashMap sort by 3 values

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, hashmap

I want to sort some data. At the moment the data is stored in a map. I know, I can't sort data in a map by value. I calculate a soccer schedule like that:

> TeamName, G+, G-, P

I want to sort first by P, then by G+, then by G-.

Every k,v is in a map like this:

```
map.put(e.getString("team_id"), 0);    
map.put(e.getString("team_id")+"G+", 0);
map.put(e.getString("team_id")+"G-", 0);
```

I know that the data structure is really bad! I think it is better to get the values into a `Collection` to do a `collection.sort`. But How can I do that?

Here is my code (the code works fine, but is unsorted and badly coded):

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, String> tab = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(int i=0; i<teams.length(); i++){                
    JSONObject e = teams.getJSONObject(i);
    //get TeamID
    map.put(e.getString("team_id"), 0);
    //Goals +
    map.put(e.getString("team_id")+"G+", 0);
    //Goals -
    map.put(e.getString("team_id")+"G-", 0);
    //standings.add(map);
    //Log.e("Team7", String.valueOf(map.get("7")));
    //Log.e("Team7", e.getString("team_id"));
}

for(int i=0; i<matchdata.length(); i++){
    JSONObject e = matchdata.getJSONObject(i);
    //calculate Points
    int myVarGoal1 = Integer.valueOf(e.getString("points_team1"));
    int myVarGoal2 = Integer.valueOf(e.getString("points_team2"));
    if ((myVarGoal1) > (myVarGoal2)){
        myPoint1 = 3;
        myPoint2 = 0;
    }
    if ((myVarGoal1) < (myVarGoal2)){
        myPoint1 = 0;
        myPoint2 = 3;
    }
    if ((myVarGoal1) == (myVarGoal2)){
        myPoint1 = 1;
        myPoint2 = 1;
    }
    int calc1 = (map.get(e.getString("id_team1")) + myPoint1);
    int calc2 = (map.get(e.getString("id_team2")) + myPoint2);
    map.put("id",  Integer.valueOf(i));
    map.put(e.getString("id_team1"), calc1);
    map.put(e.getString("id_team2"), calc2);

    //calculate Goals
    int calcGoal1 = (map.get(e.getString("id_team1")+"G+") + myVarGoal1);
    int calcGoal2 = (map.get(e.getString("id_team1")+"G-") + myVarGoal2);
    int calcGoal3 = (map.get(e.getString("id_team2")+"G+") + myVarGoal2);
    int calcGoal4 = (map.get(e.getString("id_team2")+"G-") + myVarGoal1);
    map.put(e.getString("id_team1")+"G+", calcGoal1);
    map.put(e.getString("id_team1")+"G-", calcGoal2);
    map.put(e.getString("id_team2")+"G+", calcGoal3);
    map.put(e.getString("id_team2")+"G-", calcGoal4);
    //standings.add(map);
    //Log.e("TeamID", e.getString("id_team1"));
    //Log.e("PointsTeam7", String.valueOf(map.get("7")));
    //Log.e("GaolsTeam7", String.valueOf(map.get("7G-")));
}

for(int i=0; i<teams.length(); i++){                
    JSONObject e = teams.getJSONObject(i);
    String myTeamID = e.getString("team_id");
    int Gdif = (map.get(myTeamID+"G+")) - (map.get(myTeamID+"G-"));
    tab.put(myTeamID, e.getString("team_name") +","+ map.get(myTeamID) +","+ (map.get(myTeamID+"G+")) +":"+ (map.get(myTeamID+"G-")) +" "+ Gdif);
    //Log.e("Team7", String.valueOf(tab.get("7")));
    //Log.e("Team7", e.getString("team_id"));
    strGoals+="\n" + String.valueOf(tab.get(myTeamID));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Comparator`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: The Comparator sort the 3 seperated values? I need collect all related data into one object and sort?! Or I misinterpret it?

Comment: What do "G+", "G-", and "P" stand for?

Comment: G+ Goals (to score), G- Goals (get score), P Points

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a `TreeMap` and a `Comparator`. Can you switch to using a `TreeMap` instead? It works just like a `HashMap`, but will automatically sort your keys for you. Then you can use a `Comparator` like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    ..... do stuff .....

TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs)
    {
        // return 1 if lhs > rhs
        // return 0 if lhs = rhs
        // return -1 if lhs < rhs
        if (lhs == null && rhs == null) return 0;
        if (lhs == null) return -1;
        if (rhs == null) return 1;

        if ((lhs.endsWith("P") && (rhs.endsWith("P")))
            || (lhs.endsWith("G+") && (rhs.endsWith("G+")))
            || (lhs.endsWith("G-") && (rhs.endsWith("G-"))))
        {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
        else if (lhs.endsWith("P"))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (rhs.endsWith("P"))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            String lastLeftChar = lhs.substring(lhs.length()-1);
            String lastRightChar = rhs.substring(rhs.length()-1);

            return lastLeftChar.compareTo(lastRightChar);
        }
    }
});
treeMap.putAll(map);

// Now your treeMap is sorted by the keys!
```

Comment: that sort by key, not by value

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to first create your own class to hold related data as one single object. The exact name of the class depends on what the data is. Maybe `SoccerTeam` or `SoccerSchedule`. After you create this class, you can implement the `Comparable` interface or create a `Comparator` object that defines the sorting order.

Comment: can you give me a example how I can do this? I Try something like this: map.put(e.getString("team_id"), new TeamEntry(0, 0, 0)); with the 3 values being my G+, G- and P. But it do not work.